# Is it possible to expose 2 ports in Kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following scenario -

[image]

The position simulator will get its longitude and latitude data based on time from a gps tracker. So this position simulator has a connection to activemq, but to receive the raw data, is it possible to expose another port of this service to receive the live tracking data?

Comment: Could you specify a bit more? Not sure if I understood good. 
If you want to expose service in more than 1 port, you can just add it in YAML config like here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#multi-port-services
Or use expose `kubectl expose deployment <something> --port=80,60000 --target-port=8080`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to expose for example you `deployment` on two or more ports you can do it at least two ways.

1. Proper configuration in `YAML`.
   This method is well described in [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#multi-port-services).

   > For some Services, you need to expose more than one port. Kubernetes lets you configure multiple port definitions on a Service object. When using multiple ports for a Service, you must give all of your ports names so that these are unambiguous. For example:

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 9377
    - name: <another-name>
      protocol: TCP
      port: XXX
      targetPort: XXX
```

2. Using `kubectl expose`.

`$ kubectl exposed <resource(deployment/Replicaset/etc)> <deployment-name> --port=XXX,XYZ,ABC --target-port=XXX`

`$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80,8080,6000 --target-port=8080
service/nginx exposed`

```
$ kubectl describe svc nginx
Name:              nginx
Namespace:         default
Labels:            run=nginx
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          run=nginx
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.0.74.75
Port:              port-1  80/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.48.0.13:8080
Port:              port-2  8080/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.48.0.13:8080
Port:              port-3  6000/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.48.0.13:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

As mentioned in [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#creating-a-service)

`targetPort`: is the port the container accepts traffic on, 
`port`: is the abstracted `Service` port, which can be any port other pods use to access the Service

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking that in an isolated pod, which is only exposed to another pod, would not be possible to expose another publicly accessible node.